# C++ Structs Not Compiling... Not Initialized Properly? Not using them right?

Tags: c++, struct

I am -trying- to use nested structs/structures, and after several hours of pseudocode and attempts, the final result that I come up with doesn't work or doesn't compile.

I would like to take two vectors A and B, and compare them against each other. I set up nested struct to read the start and end point of the vector, and the vector struct itself. So I think I may be doing some wrong further below, but I am stuck.

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <cmath>
    #include <string>

    using namespace std;
struct Point    // Reads in three coordinates for point to make a three dimensional vector
{
    double x;
    double y;
    double z;
};
struct MathVector   // Struct for the start and end point of each vector.
{
    Point start;
    Point end;
};
Point ReadPoint()
{
    Point pt; // Letter distinguishes between vector A and vector B, or "letterA" and "letterB"
    double x, y, z;

    cout << "Please input the x-coordinate: " << endl;
    cin >> pt.x;
    cout << "Please input the y-coordinate: " << endl;
    cin >> pt.y;
    cout << "Please input the z-coordinate: " << endl;
    cin >> pt.z;

    return pt;
}
void DotProduct (MathVector letterA, MathVector letterB, double& a_times_b ) //formula to compute orthogonality
{
    a_times_b = (letterA.end.x - letterA.start.x)*(letterB.end.x - letterB.start.x) + (letterA.end.y - letterA.start.y)*(letterB.end.y - letterB.start.y) + (letterA.end.z - letterA.start.z)*(letterB.end.z - letterB.start.z);
}
int main()
{
    MathVector letterA;
    MathVector letterB;
    double a_times_b;

    letterA = ReadPoint();
    letterB = ReadPoint();

    DotProduct (letterA, letterB, a_times_b);

    cout << "The vector " << letterA << " compared with " << letterB << " ";
    if ( a_times_b == 0)
        cout << "is orthoganal." << endl;
    else
        cout << "is not orthoganal." << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Post the error. Also, `doesn't work` and `doesn't compile` are two different things.

Comment: Is the fact that `ReadPoint()` does not update `letter` a typo?

Comment: Be very careful comparing floating point values - small errors often creep into calculations, giving results that aren't quite what you expect.

Comment: thank for your help everybody!
one more thing though and i am on my way...
 letterA = ReadPoint();
 letterB = ReadPoint();
is saying "no match for 'operator=' in 'letterB = 
 ReadPoint()'
WHAT DOES THIS MEAN?

Comment: also saying that z is an used variable in ReadPoint, when it is clearly being used -_-

Answer (score 2):

One problem is with your `ReadPoint` whose return type is `Point`, but you're returning an instance of `MathVector`. Also, you read the input into variables which ignore eventually.

You should write `ReadPoint` as:

```
Point ReadPoint()
{
    Point p;
    cout << "Please input the x-coordinate: " << endl;
    cin >> p.x;
    cout << "Please input the y-coordinate: " << endl;
    cin >> p.y;
    cout << "Please input the z-coordinate: " << endl;
    cin >> p.z;
    return p;
}
```

Or a little better version:

```
Point ReadPoint()
{
    Point p;
    cout << "Please enter point-coordinate : " << endl;
    cin >> p.x >> p.y >> p.z; //example input : 1 2 3 
    return p;
}
```

Or,  still better is, overload `>>` operator as:

```
std::istream & operator>>(std::istream & in, Point & p)
{
    cout << "Please enter point-coordinate : " << endl;
    return cin >> p.x >> p.y >> p.z; //example input : 1 2 3 
}

//Use this as
Point pointA, pointB;
cin >> pointA >> pointB;
```

Now read a good C++ book. If you're *already* reading one, then make sure it is *really* good. Here is a list of *really* good C++ books, of all levels:

- [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: thanks Nawaz.... for now I am only learning C++ structs to skip ahead of my high school class :) If I take some programming in course uni or college, I will definately take a look

Comment: thank for your help! one more thing though and i am on my way... 
letterA = ReadPoint();
letterB = ReadPoint(); 

is saying "no match for 'operator=' in 'letterB = ReadPoint()'" WHAT DOES THIS MEAN?

Comment: You're trying to set a vector equal to a point, but you've never specified what exactly that should do. So the computer has no idea.

Answer (score 0):

1. ReadPoint returns letter of type MathVector instead of Point
2. You haven't overloaded operator << to tell it how to handle MathVector objects

Answer (score 0):

```
Point ReadPoint()
{
   MathVector letter; // Letter distinguishes between vector A and vector B, or "letterA" and "letterB"
    double x, y, z;

   cout << "Please input the x-coordinate: " << endl;
   cin >> x;
   cout << "Please input the y-coordinate: " << endl;
   cin >> y;
   cout << "Please input the z-coordinate: " << endl;
   cin >> z;

   return letter;
```

}

You didn't explain what it is you're trying to do or what errors you got, but this code makes *no* sense. You have three variables, `x`, `y`, and `z`. You fill them with values you get from the user. Then you don't do anything with those variables and return the `MathVector` created by a default constructor even though you say you're going to return a `Point`. That makes very little sense.

Comment: I created a vector, Point, that should handle three dimensions, x y z.
Then created a struct, MathVector, so that the START of a vector and the END of the vector could use the struct Point. Two of these MathVectors are created as 'A' and 'B' so that two seperate vectors can be put into a calculation.

Comment: Okay, so you need to read *4* points and load them into the `start` and `end` positions of the two vectors. You never wrote any code to do that.

Answer (score 0):

`letterA` and `letterB` are of type `MathVector`

```
 MathVector letterA;
        MathVector letterB;
        double a_times_b;

        letterA = ReadPoint();
        letterB = ReadPoint();
```

you should create another method to read `Mathvector`.. as you are doing with `Point`.

and in method `ReadPoint`

return type must be Point .. If you reading point then do calculation here to create the object of `MathVector` go tet `startpoint` and `endpoint` format.

Answer (score 0):

No match for 'operator=' error means that there's no function for assigning a MathVector to a Point. You are calling ReadPoint() which returns a Point and trying to assign the returned value to a variable of type MathVector. The compiler can't create a 'convertion' function automatically. You have to provide one yourself. Perhaps what you meant was

```
letterA.start = ReadPoint();
letterA.end   = ReadPoint();
```